# Vanishing tate of a $p$-complete spectra

Tags: higher-algebra, ring-spectra, completion

I was told: if $X$ is bdd below and $p$-complete spectra then $X^{tC_q}$ vanishes for primes $q \not= p$.

I do not see how this holds.

---

I am aware from [I.2.9](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01799) that if $X$ is bdd. below, then $X^{tC_q} \simeq \left(X^{\hat{}}_q \right)^{tC_P}$.

Here $\hat{}_p$ denotes the $p$-completion of $X$.  I believe my problem would be resolved if: we show  $q$-completion of a $p$-complete spectra is trivial - is this true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is how you prove this.

Recall that $(-)^\wedge_p \simeq L_{\mathbb{S}/p}(-)$, where $L_E(-)$ is the Bousfield localization with respect to $E$. Now, multiplication by $q$ mod $p$ is an equivalence, so multiplication by $q$ becomes a weak equivalence on $p$-complete spectra. Then $\mathbb{S}/q\wedge X\simeq X/q\simeq 0$ for $p$-complete spectra, and so $X^\wedge_q\simeq 0$.